# (Android/Kotlin) Correct way to navigate to another fragment without using drawer

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, navigation-drawer

So I'm new to Kotlin and Android, and I clearly don't understand how we are supposed to navigate from one fragment to another using NavController. I started from the Drawer layout template available in Android Studio and I have added a few fragments to the navGraph. I can access them with the side drawer without any issue. So far so good.

Now I have added a button in my home_fragment.xml (fragment `nav_home`), which is the start destination (`app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home"`) in my navigation. I added a setOnClickListener to the said button in my HomeFragment.kt in order to directly navigate to another fragment (let's say fragment2), without the drawerLayout. I am doing so with:

```
binding.calculatorButton.setOnClickListener { 
val navHostFragment = activity?.supportFragmentManager?.findFragmentById(.R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
navController.navigate(com.example.doughhero.R.id.nav_fragment2)
}
```

The problem is that I cannot acces the home_fragment from the drawer anymore: when selecting the home fragment, it goes to fragment2 (and fragment2 is highlighted in the drawer menu). But when I click the back arrow, it goes back to the home fragment (which is correct per my navigation graph).

I assume I am not navigating "correctly" to fragment2. What is the correct way of doing so, and what am I missing? Thanks!

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_fragment2, R.id.nav_fragment3, R.id.nav_fragment4
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    }



    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

**ANSWER**

The navGraph should've have been provided to the appBarConfiguration:

```
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayout)
```

instead of

```
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.nav_home,R.id.nav_fragment2,R.id.nav_fragment3, R.id.nav_fragment4), drawerLayout)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with DrawerLayout, but to me it seems you're overdoing it.

Keep in mind that a normal and simple navigation works like this:

1. You have an `Activity` that contains a `FragmentContainerView` or similar
2. You set the `app:navGraph` of that container.
3. You add the fragments to the graph and create the actions
4. To navigate, you just need to call `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action)`

If you're having trouble, I suggest that first you try to create a small navigation in a separate project instead of working directly with the drawer.

Comment: I think I can correctly navigate from one fragment to another and my navGraph actions are working as expected. What is incorrect is my drawer menu seems to be "out of sync" with what is the current fragment. Hope that makes sense.